# Rails displaying tables of a has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to wrap my head around Rails and have come into some difficulty trying to understand why somethings work and others do not

For example, having 2 tables:

Class User

```
table users
email:string
password:string
```

class Profile

```
table profiles
firstname:string
lastname:string
city:string
user_id:integer
```

Now each user should have 1 profile.

so in the module user.rb I have

```
has_one :profile
```

and in profile.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

now all I want to do is show both tables in a table

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>User_ID</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Password digest</th>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>City</th>
 </tr>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
 <tr>
  <td><%= user.id %></td>
  <td><%= user.email %></td>
  <td><%= user.password %></td>
  <td><%= user.profile.firstname %></td>%></td>
  <td><%= user.profile.lastname %></td>%></td>
  <td><%= user.profile.city %></td>%></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

I have a controller Show with an index page

```
def index
 #this works
 @users = User.all(:include => :profile)
end
```

This snippet of code I have found works, it displays the table properly.

But I have a list of other code that I've gathered/cobbled by trying to get this to work, that do not work.

So this list of codes would have been inside the def index individually tring to connect the two tables

1. @users = @users.build_profile()
   Throws error: undefined method `build_profile' for nil:NilClass
2. @users = @users.profile
   Throws error: undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass
3. @users = @user.collect { |user| user.profile }
   Throws error: undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass
4. @users = Profile.find(:all)
   Throws error: undefined method `email' for #Profile:0x46da5a0

   ```
   <% @users.each do |user| %>
   <tr>
   <td><%= user.id %></td>
   <td><%= user.email %></td>
   <td><%= user.password %></td>
   <td><%= user.proflie.firstname %></td>
   ```
5. @users = @profile.create_user()
   Throws error: undefined method `create_user' for nil:NilClass
6. @users = @users.profiles
   Throws error: undefined method `profiles' for nil:NilClass
7. @users = @user.each { |user| user.profiles }
   Throws error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Why are all of these other ones failing, they seemed to work for other users that had similar problems (connecting two tables with a 1 to zero relationship)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The majority of the problems you are experiencing are caused just by the fact that you are calling methods on `nil`. You need to initialize the `@users` collection before you can call methods on it. Also make sure that you actually have some users in the database.

Getting all of the users:

```
@users = User.all(:include => :profile)
@users = User.includes(:profile) # I prefer this syntax
```

Building a profile. Note that you need to call this on one particular `User`, not on the collection given by the `all` method:

```
@profile = @users.first.build_profile # This won't actually save the profile
```

Getting the first user's profile

```
@profile = @users.first.profile
```

Getting all profiles:

```
@profiles = @users.collect { |user| user.profile }
```

Getting the first user's email:

```
@email = @users.first.profile.email
```

The rest is just a slightly modified version of the above.